# Fetching array from json object in Typescript angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, multidimensional-array, angular-material

I have a JSON object which consists of string elements along with one element which is of type array. I don't know how to fetch JSON object of object. Below is my code snippet:

```
getData(){
    this.productService.getliveData().subscribe(resp => {
      this.catDta = resp['categories'];
      const products: any = [];
      const jsonobject = resp['categories'];
      this.newestItems=jsonobject['cat_products'];
      console.log('newwest items2',jsonobject['cat_products']);

    });
  }
```

I just want to know how to fetch cat_products which is of type array from categories object.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here below is the JSON:

```
{
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Suspension",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "deleted": "0",
            "cat_image": "https://www.insertcart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/category.png",
            "expanded": false,
            "**cat_products**": [
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "title": "Suspension Rodes",
                    "description": "",
                    "cat_id": "3",
                    "unit_type": "",
                    "item_type": "product",
                    "rate": "12",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "workplace_id": null,
                    "stock": null,
                    "product_image": "https://i.insider.com/5e69490554f25c19106866f2?width=700&format=jpeg&auto=webp",
                    "amount": 1,
                    "sale": true,
                    "featured": true,
                    "fav": false,
                    "res": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Brake Pads",
                    "description": "Testing",
                    "cat_id": "3",
                    "unit_type": "No",
                    "item_type": "product",
                    "rate": "10",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "workplace_id": "2",
                    "stock": "5",
                    "product_image": "https://i.insider.com/5e69490554f25c19106866f2?width=700&format=jpeg&auto=webp",
                    "amount": 1,
                    "sale": true,
                    "featured": true,
                    "fav": false,
                    "res": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Brake Pads",
                    "description": "Testing",
                    "cat_id": "3",
                    "unit_type": "No",
                    "item_type": "product",
                    "rate": "10",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "workplace_id": "3",
                    "stock": "1",
                    "product_image": "https://i.insider.com/5e69490554f25c19106866f2?width=700&format=jpeg&auto=webp",
                    "amount": 1,
                    "sale": true,
                    "featured": true,
                    "fav": false,
                    "res": true
                }
            ]
        },
```

I need to access cat_products. Please help me.

Comment: You code should work. Where is the problem?  In case that resp is an object (and not  a json string):    this.newestItems=resp['cat_products']

Comment: response is jsonobject and inside jsonobject there is an array of object called cat_products but i am getting undefined error

Comment: Can you show us the full json?

Comment: getData(){
    this.productService.getliveData().subscribe(resp => { console.info(resp['cat_products']); });
}

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

If resp is the object from your json structure, then you can have access to it's products via:

```
const products = resp['cat_products'];
```

In case that resp is a json string, you can convert it first via:

```
if (typeof resp === 'string') resp = JSON.parse(resp);
```

Comment: categories is the main object inside which i have a n arraylist with the key cat_products which i am unable to retireve... please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You used this line:

```
this.catDta = resp['categories'];
```

Which will be undefined because you don't have `"categories": ...` in your JSON.

Replace your function with this one:

```
getData(){
    this.productService.getliveData().subscribe(resp => {
      // this.catDta = resp['categories'];
      // const products: any = [];
      const jsonobject = resp;
      this.newestItems= resp['cat_products'];
      console.log('newwest items2', jsonobject['cat_products']);

    });
  }
```